# Having problems installing a Windows app via power shell? error 0x80073CF3?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, windows-store-apps

I am not a developer or anything.I just want to install this game and i don't have visual studio installed

add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict
validation.

Windows cannot install package A278AB0D.ModernCombat5Blackout because this package depends on anot
couldn't be found. This package requires minimum version 2.11.2154.0 of framework Microsoft.Media.
published by any publisher to install; the frameworks with name Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2
user are Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2_2.8.1947.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2_2.8.1947.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Provide the correct framewor
Windows cannot install package A278AB0D.ModernCombat5Blackout because this package depends on anot
couldn't be found. This package requires minimum version 2.11.2154.0 of framework Microsoft.Media.
published by any publisher to install; the frameworks with name Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2
user are Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2_2.8.1947.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Media.PlayReadyClient.2_2.8.1947.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Provide the correct framework

Answer (score 0):

You get this error message because you don't have the required Visual Studio 2012 frameworks. Solved by downloading and installing VS 2012.